# How do I eliminate keys from MediaWiki External Data JSON?

Tags: json, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am using MediaWiki 1.27 with the External Data extension. The external data is only available in JSON format. Unfortunately, the data returns duplicate key names, where some are nested. See example:

```
[
    {
        "created": 1481938823000,
        "name": "3D Thursdays & Open House",
        "venue": {
            "name": "HacDC",
            ...
        },
        "group": {
            "name": "HacDC",
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

When attempting to display the data with:

```
{{#get_web_data:
url=https://api.meetup.com/hac-dc/events?scroll=next_upcoming&page=10
|format=JSON
|data=local_date=local_date,local_time=local_time,name=name,link=link,duration=duration
|cache seconds=0
}} 

{| class="wikitable"
! Date
! Time
! Event {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{local_date}}}
{{!}} {{{local_time}}}
{{!}} [{{{link}}} {{{name}}}]
}}
|}
```

MediaWiki appears to have no obvious way to ignore the nested `name` keys, and displays an entry for "3D Thursday & Open House" (correct) and "HacDC" and "HacDC" (both incorrect).

Is there a way to explicitly exclude the `venue` and `group` "dictionaries" or display only "outer" values?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new format `json with jsonpath` (upgrade, at least, the extension):

```
{{#get_web_data:
 url=https://api.meetup.com/hac-dc/events?scroll=next_upcoming&page=10
|format=json with jsonpath
|data=local_date=$.*.local_date,local_time=$.*.local_time,name=$.*.name,link=$.*.link,duration=$.*.duration
|cache seconds=10
}}{| class="wikitable"
! Date
! Time
! Duration
! Event {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{local_date}}}
{{!}} {{{local_time}}}
{{!}} {{{duration}}}
{{!}} [{{{link}}} {{{name}}}]
}}
|}
```